# parallax.js causes lags while scrolling page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, parallax.js

I have a problem on website where I'm using parallax.js ( matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/ ). While scrolling page down to section where parallax.js appear it causes huge lags. Firefox doesn't have this problem.

Here is a screen from Chrome timeline:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J77Tm.jpg

[An example here](http://www.archipictura.com/laka)

I'm sure that size of images doesn't matter because it happen even on 5kB images.

Comment: It's not the size of the file that matters, but the time it takes to repaint. You might look into a [3D-CSS parallax solution](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) instead.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: See https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/pull/90. If you could find a way to contact the author to get him to come back and accept this commit, that would be great.